# Can you have multiple grids on the same page with different themes?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a master/detail setup using jqGrid and jQuery. Is it possible to have the detail grid use a different theme/skin than the master grid?

I see a setting to change the images folder, but it looks to me like `grid.css` would have to be the same for the entire page. Has anyone tried? Or do you have any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the documentation and it seems as though you can't because if you had multiple grids they would all use the same CSS rules by default. If you load in another grid.css stylesheet then it will just take precedence over the previous one. They don't seem to provide a mechanism to choose the theme for each grid.